# php while statement, except on post id

Tags: php

i got the following php.  and what i want is this loop to exclude specific post ids

The following field will generate the id i wish to exclude

```
<?php the_field('excludeid'); ?>
```

(this field basicly checks if a checkbox is marked on the page, and if it is, it will output the page id)

So if it checks page id 701, checkbox is marked, it will output 701 (and otherwise it outputs nothing)

so in the loop i want to check if the page it loops for, matches with that output, if it does, it needs to skip it

```
<?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
Do something, except when page id is equal to <?php the_field('excludeid'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Edit,  this is what i have now:

```
    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
<?php if( $post->ID == 686) continue; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

That works, but when i change the 686 to "the_field('excludeid')" (which outputs 686) it doesnt work.
I am a total newb in php, so manybe i am doing something dumb here XD

Comment: Use `if` statement for that. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: @romanHocke 
Do you mean something like this (i am totally new to php):
    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
if( $post->ID == <?php the_field('excludeid'); ?>)
continue;  
     else
     {
do my stuff
     }

<?php endwhile; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` cycle is a type of conditional, but in loop, you can set any type of logic inside its arguments. In this case you iterate about `$parent->have_post()`

```
    while($parent->has_post() && (!in_array($parent->the_post()->id, the_field('excludeid')) {
      // your logic
    }
```

I don't know how is your business code, but is that, you must know that `while` is that a conditional, but it loop

Comment: this didnt seem to work for me, could that be because The field "excludeid" is only on the post itself?
I edited my post with what i have now

Comment: ok, i need to know how is $parent. what is... how is its structure, to help you

Comment: i am just a dumb idiot.... i overlooked something in my plugin documentation.  The_field  outputs the data,  get_field  grabs it.  Once i changed that it worked perfectly fine.

Thanks a lot for the help, it is much appreciated